# iPhone Change App Name

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

I am trying to change my App Name, in iTunes Connect for an app update.  I do not see the option.

Is this still possible or did Apple remove this feature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can definitely do it. It's on the version details page, under app localizations - you need to click edit there and then you can change the app name. You can only do it when you're uploading a new version though so make sure you do that on the new version you've created in iTC rather than the existing version.

Comment: I do not see that option, and the app status is waiting for upload.

Comment: Go to your app. Then go to the new version. Then scroll down a bit and under 'App Localizations', click 'Edit'.

Comment: You've posted a screenshot of changing the version details - it's below that, under 'App Localizations'.

Answer (score 5):

Click this
[image]

then this
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I do not remember it being here

Comment: I marked mattjgalloway answer as correct, since he gave me the correct answer fist, but thanks a lot.