# Updating existing iphone application

Tags: iphone, ipad

I had a iphone game application in the Appstore, but few days ago i got a mail from apple that I have to chnage the name of the application,they got a mail from a company that this name is their trademark name . So i decided to change the name.I need to know that can i update the existing application for name changing ? Or do I need to delete the binary and release it as a new app? 
When i update the exsting app with the changed name of that app, will it reflect it in itunes store?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You do not need to delete the binary - just submit the name change as an update, and select the option that says your update is because of a legal issue to fasttrack it.

Comment: @Marc B they will not reply.they are busy.lol

Comment: @stackiphone: I suppose so, they must be laughing at the piles of money flowing in, and at the funny pictures people are posting of Map screwups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can change the name of existing app, but it will only be reflect when you upload new version of it. [This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9487875/iphone-change-app-name)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it would reflect automatically in the itunes store, you do your bit and apple would manage the rest :)